# A Specific Representation of $SO(3)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, mathematical-physics, rotations

I am studying quantum mechanics, particularly angular momentum and rotations at the moment. The notes I am using are K. Schulten's [*Notes on Quantum Mechanics*](https://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Services/Class/PHYS480/qm_PDF/QM_Book.pdf). In these notes there is a particular representation of $SO(3)$ discussed (on page 104), namely one that acts on elements of $\mathcal C^\infty(\mathbb R^3)$. It does so in the following manner. For any element $R_n(\vartheta)$, where $\vartheta$ is the angle of rotation and $n$ is the axis of rotation, we define the linear map $\rho (R_n(\vartheta))$ via $$\rho(R_n(\vartheta))\psi(r) = \psi(R_n(\vartheta)^{-1}r).$$ The notes claim that this map satisfies the homomorphism property, but upon investigating I end up getting that $$\rho(R_n(\vartheta)R_m(\varphi))\psi(r) = \rho(R_m(\varphi))\rho(R_n(\vartheta))\psi(r)=\psi(R_m(\varphi)^{-1}R_n(\vartheta)^{-1}r).$$ The notes claim that this is equal to $\rho(R_n(\vartheta))\rho(R_m(\varphi))\psi(r)$, but I don't know how to justify this.

Comment: Just note that if $A \in SO_3$, $\rho(A)\psi =\psi \circ L_{A^{-1}}$ where $L_x$ is left multiplication by $x$. Now, $\rho(AB)\psi=\psi \circ L_{(AB)^{-1}}$, and $L_{(AB)^{-1}}=L_{B^{-1}A^{-1}}=L_{B^{-1}}\circ L_{A^{-1}}$, so $\rho(AB)\psi=(\psi \circ L_{B^{-1}}) \circ L_{A^{-1}}=\rho(A)(\psi \circ L_{B^{-1}}) =\rho(A)\rho(B)\psi$.

Comment: @Mindlack it makes a lot more sense using the left multiplication. Thanks for resolving the situation!

Comment: Note that this is not really specific to rotations. If you have a group $G$ acting (on the left) on a set $X$, then $G$ acts (on the left) on functions $X\to Y$ (for any fixed set $Y$) by $g\cdot f: x\mapsto f(g^{-1}\cdot x)$. If we used the more natural $g\cdot f: x\mapsto f(g\cdot x)$, that would be an action on the right. Here $G=SO(3)$, $X= \mathbb{R}^3$ and $Y=\mathbb{R}$. The only extra bit it that the action preserves smooth functions (and that is of course because rotations are smooth).